# How to write SUMPRODUCT where one array is (A1:A10 = B1:B1000)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumproduct

I am trying to write a SUMPRODUCT formula which sums values based on multiple criteria. One criteria is matching a list of ten codes to a thousand codes associated with the values I want summed.

My simplified equation is this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($C3=$D$1:$D$1000), --($A$1:$A$10=$B$1:$B$1000), ('Cons and EP FY16'!$H$1:$H$1000))
```

where C and D are names, A and B are the codes I want to match, and H is the value to be summed.

The above equation returns an error. However, if you replace the `$A$1:$A$10` with a single code, say `99203`, it works.

I would appreciate any help you can lend me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MATCH:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($C3=$D$1:$D$1000)*(ISNUMBER(MATCH($B$1:$B$1000,$A$1:$A$10,0))), ('Cons and EP FY16'!$H$1:$H$1000))
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you need something to return the word (in this case, the most common word will be the word you're looking for) for that range, so try this:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--($C3=INDEX($D$1:$D$1000,MODE(MATCH($D$1:$D$1000,$D$1:$D$1000,0)))), --(INDEX($A$1:$A$10,MODE(MATCH($A$1:$A$10,$A$1:$A$10,0)))=INDEX($B$1:$B$1000,MODE(MATCH($B$1:$B$1000,$B$1:$B$1000,0)))), ('Cons and EP FY16'!$H$1:$H$1000))`